# Websphere 9.0.5.10 java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: websphere

Am using WebSphere 9.0.5.10 and trying to connect DB2 database over SSL port.
I tried to retrieve the certificate from DB2 database by using the below procedure.

Import the database server certificate.

1.**Open the WebSphere Application Server administrative console.**

Security > SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates > {NodeDefKeystore}

> Signer certificates > Retrieve from port.
> Clicked Retrieve from port.

Enter the host name and security port of the database server.

Type an alias name for the certificate.

Click Retrieve signer information.

Click OK to save the configuration.

2.**Configure the data source to support SSL connections.**

Select Resources > JDBC > Data sources.

Select WebSphere Commerce database DataSource demo in the data source list, where database can be either DB2 or Oracle.

Update the port number in the Common and required data source properties section. Enter the value of the security port that you set in the database server.

Clicked Apply.

In the Additional Properties section, select Custom properties.

Clicked New
Enter sslConnection in the Name field, and enter true in the Value field.

Click OK to save the configurations.

Post service restart, tried to check the database connection and got below error.

Someone please help to resolve the issue.

**Error**: The test connection operation failed for data source on server nodeagent at node  with the following exception: java.sql.SQLException: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.29.24] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, or socket output stream. Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1). Message: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = -4,499. View JVM logs for further details.

Answer (score 0):

The Test Connection function makes a best attempt at connecting, but some security requirements are not supported by this, since Test Connection is not an equivalent application.

Test Connection does not have the same quality of function available as an application, hence, an application in this case is the best method to test any database connections.

Another document that is well worth checking is:

WebSphere Application Server Data Source driver connection over SSL with Database server
https://community.ibm.com/community/user/wasdevops/blogs/ajit-jariwala/2021/10/06/websphere-application-server-data-source-driver-c

Otherwise it's more of a DB2 JDBC Driver issue with the error -4499

Perhaps, also test the very latest JDBC Driver 4.32.28
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads

Hope it helps!
Dave

Comment: Hello dave,Am able to see the below error in Db2diag.log from DB2 server. DIA3604E The SSL function "gsk_secure_soc_init" failed with the return code "402" in "sqlccSSLSocketSetup".  When tried to hit testconnection from Websphere Application server.